# How to install `yq` with Mach-O 64-bit executable? I got error `bad CPU executable`

Tags: macos, homebrew, executable, mach-o, yq

I'm not very familiar with Mac system, so I used `brew install jq` and `brew install yq`,
then I got:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/jq
/usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/jq: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ file /usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/yq
/usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/yq: Mach-O executable i386
```

Then when I run something and it gave me an error:

```
/usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/yq: Bad CPU type in exectable
```

I'm thinking this can be fixed if I can install `yq` with `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`, does anyone know how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unexpected of `brew` to install an i386 binary that can't work on macOS >= 10.15

Instead of recompiling `yq`, you can just download the [stand-alone binary](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases), put the `yq` executable somewhere in your PATH and you're done with the installation:

- `yq_darwin_amd64` is for Macs with Intel CPU
- `yq_darwin_arm64` is for Macs with Apple CPU

Comment: Thank you, turns out the issue wasn't because of `brew`, but somehow I have two `yq` executables on my machine (one is 32-bit and another is 64-bit). But thanks for your answer.